# Bookmark application that shows bookmarks in Google search

Tags: browser-addons, bookmarks, google-search

I have a lot of bookmarks, but do not look at them, because they are cluttered and hard to find.

Is there any application/addon that shows results from my bookmarks at the top of the results page, when I perform a Google search for something similar?

Please don't guess and give answer, I am sure some of you will think that If I use Google bookmarks, these results will come at top, but they don't, or maybe sometimes they do, but not always and it's not reliable. So I am searching for some software/addon which takes care of the bookmark synchronization and affects the result of the search engine.

Comment: There may be a Greasemonkey script which can do it.  http://userscripts.org/scripts/search?q=google+search

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked [diigo.com](http://diigo.com)? they provide such functionality. Though your bookmarks won't appear on top but diigo will alert if there will be any match in your bookmarks and will allow you to see those matches in the sidebar on your google results page.